# Q: Jssor Slider , only showing first picture when I use it with ionic tabs

Tags: html, slider, ionic-framework, jssor

I am beginning to learn ionic and hope to use jssor slider in my app.

I am trying carousel slider and I am able to use it in the same html file. BUT when I have created tabs with ionic and tried to place the codes in on of my tabs. it wont work.

Could anyone or jssor please help ?

my code for index.html is as below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="bb">


    <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->

    <ion-nav-view>


  </body>
</html>
```

and my code for the tab that is to display the slider is as below :

```html
<ion-view view-title="Home">
  <ion-content class="padding">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.slider.js"></script>

    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var options = {
          $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
          $AutoPlaySteps: 4,                                  //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
          $AutoPlayInterval: 4000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
          $PauseOnHover: 1,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

          $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                  //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
          $SlideDuration: 160,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
          $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
          $SlideWidth: 200,                                   //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
          //$SlideHeight: 150,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
          $SlideSpacing: 3,                      //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
          $DisplayPieces: 4,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
          $ParkingPosition: 0,                              //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
          $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
          $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
          $DragOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

          $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
            $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
            $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
            $AutoCenter: 0,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
            $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
            $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
            $SpacingX: 0,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
            $SpacingY: 0,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
            $Orientation: 1                                 //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
          },

          $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
            $ChanceToShow: 1,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
            $AutoCenter: 2,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
            $Steps: 4                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
          }
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

        //responsive code begin
        //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
        function ScaleSlider() {
          var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
          if (bodyWidth)
            jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 809));
          else
            window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }
        ScaleSlider();

        $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        //responsive code end
      });
    </script>
    <!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
    <!-- To move inline styles to css file/block, please specify a class name for each element. -->
    <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 809px; height: 150px; overflow: hidden;">

      <!-- Loading Screen -->
      <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
        <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;
                background-color: #000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
                top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Slides Container -->
      <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 809px; height: 150px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div><img u="image" src="http://www.independent.co.uk/incoming/article8465213.ece/alternates/w620/v2-cute-cat-picture.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/articles/baby-animals/Baby-Animals-001.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/articles/baby-animals/Baby-Animals-004.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/articles/baby-animals/Baby-Animals-005.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/articles/baby-animals/Baby-Animals-007.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/articles/baby-animals/Baby-Animals-003.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="http://www.independent.co.uk/incoming/article8465213.ece/alternates/w620/v2-cute-cat-picture.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/articles/baby-animals/Baby-Animals-001.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/articles/baby-animals/Baby-Animals-004.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/articles/baby-animals/Baby-Animals-005.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/articles/baby-animals/Baby-Animals-007.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/articles/baby-animals/Baby-Animals-003.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="http://www.independent.co.uk/incoming/article8465213.ece/alternates/w620/v2-cute-cat-picture.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/articles/baby-animals/Baby-Animals-001.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/articles/baby-animals/Baby-Animals-004.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/articles/baby-animals/Baby-Animals-005.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/articles/baby-animals/Baby-Animals-007.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/articles/baby-animals/Baby-Animals-003.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="http://www.independent.co.uk/incoming/article8465213.ece/alternates/w620/v2-cute-cat-picture.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/articles/baby-animals/Baby-Animals-001.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/articles/baby-animals/Baby-Animals-004.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/articles/baby-animals/Baby-Animals-005.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/articles/baby-animals/Baby-Animals-007.jpg" /></div>

      </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Thank you so much for the help in advance

Comment: As you page is rendered by ionic, may be the `jQuery(document).ready` event would not fire.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But if I add the jquery separately in the second file alone to display the slider, the jquery event would fire. What do you suggest me to make it work ?

Comment: Please try to initialize jssor slider after ionic render complete.

Comment: I tried ionicplatform.ready and I also tried the non-jquery version of jssor and they both didnt work. I have been researching this for hours online and still have no answer. Is this a bug with ionic view ?